# Emulate github service hooks wih curl

Tags: json, curl, github, urlencode

I have a service listening to github service hooks, to perform automatic deployment. Sometimes I need to trigger this manually (without github intervention). For that, I am emulating the POST request that github is sending (post-receive-URLs).

My data (`my.json`) looks like this (a limited subset of what github is sending - I do not need more):

```
{
  "action"      : "deploy_from_scratch_with_bundle",
  "pusher"      : { "email" : "my@email.com" },
  "ref"         : "refs/heads/master"
}
```

And I try to POST with curl:

```
curl -X POST $URL --data-urlencode "@my.json" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

The problem is that github is POSTing like this:

```
payload=%7B%22pusher%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22none%22%7D%2C%22repository%22%3
A%7B%22name%22%3A%liferay-plugins%22%2C%22created_at%22%3A%222011%2F12%2F07%2011%3A52...
```

See that `payload=` there? This looks like a form field. I do not know how to combine form fields with urlencoding. To POST form fields, I would do it like this:

```
curl -X POST $URL -F "payload=@my.json"
```

But the JSON would not be url encoded. How to I get both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`curl $URL --data-urlencode payload@my.json`