# Emulate github hook with curl with secret

Tags: curl, github, openssl, hmac, webhooks

I have a need similar to [Emulate github service hooks wih curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119299/emulate-github-service-hooks-wih-curl), but I'm also using a secret in my webhook, and it's not working properly.

Here is what I'm doing as a post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  tmpfile=$(mktemp --suffix=.json)

  cat << EOF > $tmpfile
  {
    "ref": "${refname}"
  }
EOF

  sig=$(cat "${tmpfile}" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "${WEBHOOK_SECRET}" | awk '{print "X-Hub-Signature: sha1="$2}')

  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "${sig}" --data-urlencode "payload@${tmpfile}" http://webhook:9000/hooks/r10k

  rm -f "${tmpfile}"
done
```

The webhook (which works with github) complains that the signature is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was coming from the carriage return at the end of the input stream in the openssl command.

I changed to this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev refname; do
  tmpfile=$(mktemp --suffix=.json)

  data="{\"ref\": \"${refname}\"}"

  sig=$(echo -n "${data}" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "%{WEBHOOK_SECRET}" | awk '{print "X-Hub-Signature: sha1="$2}')

  curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "${sig}" --data "${data}" http://webhook:9000/hooks/r10k

  rm -f "${tmpfile}"
done
```

and it worked.